# v-if breaks nuxt ssr

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo

If I use fetched data (fetchPolicy: `'cache-and-network'`) from apollo in v-if, it will throw
`vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

```
<template>
  <div
    <div v-if="test">
      {{ test }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

but if I use it just as variable to render it works fine.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>
```

The data in real usage is object, that I need to conditionaly render and pass to another components with v-if.

I have tried geting the data trough get, doing watch over the data and seting them manually, but eventually everything broke.

regarding comment:
if I console the `test` data it will go -> `true` on server -> `false` on client and then `true` on the client again, if I remove the `test` from `v-if` it goes:  `true` on server and `true` on client

this has nothing to do with structure, in real project it has bunch of components and it works just fine if the data isnt used in condition

Comment: What is the server-side content like?

Comment: It's been a long time I haven't worked with Nuxt but I see that this question has still no relevant answer. Any update on your side @Lukáš Gibo Vaic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, I have fixed it by setting `cache-and-network` after the mount and all works just fine.

```
mounted() {
  this.$apollo.queries.getCampaign.setOptions({
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea, why this helped?

Comment: no I dont, and Iam long gone from this, so cant really help you sorry

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make the root element of a component conditionnally disappear, which creates an inconsistency in the virtual DOM.

Can you try:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="test">
      {{ test }}
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Instead of using arbitrary `<div>`, use `<template v-if="test">` instead.

Comment: Even if I do that, it doesnt work, in real exmaple there is bunch of components, and all are in wrapper component, this is all cause by the one tick when apollo returns no data.

Answer (score 1):

from my experience, nuxt will failed in SSR if you are using v-if unless you wrap in `<no-ssr>` or `<client-only>`

Comment: really need it to work on server, so this kinda makes no sense for me

Answer (score 0):

SSR is sometimes difficult to debug and such problems occure quite often.

https://ssr.vuejs.org/#why-ssr

> some external libraries may need special treatment to be able to run
> in a server-rendered app.

This may be the point. Some vue-components cannot be run via SSR out of the box. This is why I asked about the content from the server.

So the easiest fix could be to wrap your component with the `<no-ssr>` tag. You can do this for each component separatly to find out which one causes the problem.
Once you have isolated the component you can keep the `<no-ssr>` tag on it and migrate it's functions to the mounted area of your client component.

Comment: no-ssr is not an option, its all custom components, its all about usage the data from query in `if` statement, once again as I wrote in question if I set apollo to cache-and-network for one tick the cache is empty

Answer (score 0):

If it is a small component you can also use v-show instead.